# Is there any way to determine format of given byte data

Tags: python

Hi guys I've encounter some questions about byte data in python struct.

```
>>>from struct import pack , unpack
>>>x=pack('h',1850)
>>>x
b':\x07'
>>>len(x)
2
>>>unpack('h',x)
1850
```

so, this makes me think about it .Cause some projects shows len(data)*[format] for unpack data for e.g

```
#assumed data is tuple
>>>unpack(len(data)*h,data)
```

our data is only one integer , but lenght (len) of it shows 2

imagine ve have a bigger data and we want to unpack it .
How we can unpack it without knowing format of data.

Comment: You can't  - you need to know the layout or encoding scheme in advance.

Comment: i thought some hackers hacks data with this ways.And then this thought was created .Thank you for this.